# Permutation of the posson equation

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

I have the poisson matrix A, I want to reduce it to the following block matrix: 
$$ A=\begin{bmatrix}
A_{11} & A{12} \\
A_{21} & A_{22} 
\end{bmatrix} $$, 
where $A_{11}$ and $A_{22}$ are diagonal matrices, in order to apply sor at this block matrix.

How can I do ? Any hint ?

Comment: I suppose you want the [red-black ordering](http://www.cfm.brown.edu/people/gk/chap7/img271.gif).

Comment: yes ! but I don't know how to do it

Comment: What do you mean by "how to do it"? Exactly how it is on that picture.

Comment: I don't understand how can I reach that exprression of A, with a permutatioon ?